# how to make my portable device an adb device?

Tags: android

I'm working on android studio. I want to run my app but android studio cant find any device.

Moreover my device shows as portable device when plugged with USB instead of other devices. I have already enabled USB debugging on my android .Please help me .

[image]

Comment: do you have the google android usb driver? see here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the drivers of your device... and restart your pc. It's should work if you have developer option on your device and USB Debugging is checked. Anyway which device are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Install pda from [here](http://pdanet.co/) (adb driver)

And enable usb debugging in your phone and try again